# DIV content hide/show based on URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, pentaho

In html page am having an `div-reportControlPanel` as below . I have included another `div-reportControlPanel1` as same with different id .

```
<div id="reportControlPanel" class="pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr pentaho-shadow">
<div id="promptPanel" class="pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr"></div>
</div>

<div id="reportControlPanel1" class="pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr pentaho-shadow">
<div id="promptPanel" class="pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr"></div>
 </div>
```

Here Am show/hide the `div's` based on `url` am triggering .

```
    if(prptName == "css.prpt")
{
alert("if");
document.getElementById("reportControlPanel").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("reportControlPanel1").style.display = 'block';
}
```

But as am using same sub Div-**promptPanel** under two different `div` my content is not loading properly . `promptPanel` is  `pentaho system` used `div`. I am trying to have an another `div` to modify some `css` for my `prpt`.

Thanks.

Comment: An id is meant to be unique on the page. Only one element should have an id of `promptPanel`. To target multiple elements using a shared property, you could use a `class`, such as `pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr`.

Comment: Can you use jquery? You could add the ID later on like: `$('.pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr > div').attr('id', 'promptPanel');` depending on wich DIV actually loaded (depending on the url)

Comment: The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what Moishe said to you already: `id` are meant to be unique. You currently have two `promptPanel` id's, which means the second one will likely never be called. Now, you could use javascript, but with minimal knowledge of what your code looks like you could use a simple hash url + some basic css.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('#url').html($(this).prop('href'));
  });
});
```

```css
div.pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr {
  display: none;
}
div.pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr .pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr {
  display: block;
}
:target {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="url"></div>
<a href="#reportControlPanel1">"Open" panel 1</a>
<a href="#reportControlPanel2">"Open" panel 2</a>
<div id="reportControlPanel1" class="pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr pentaho-shadow">
  <div id="promptPanel" class="pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr">
    this is some text in the first control panel.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="reportControlPanel2" class="pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr pentaho-shadow">
  <div id="promptPanel" class="pentaho-rounded-panel-bottom-lr">
    this is some text in the second control panel
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually promptPanel is an id used by pentaho s/w to display the parameters inside the reportpanel . I am not supposed to edit that div id .. I need a similar div for my prpt (file) where i want to make some css changes . Css will be specified in default penatho system files where i can add reportControlPanel1 css .

Comment: Main thing is like i need to change the css property based on the url am triggering . I amnot supposed to edit the default Div - reportcontrolpanel  which will affect the other users using pentaho reports .

Comment: If you would try my example on a full webpage you would see that the location changes when you click on either of those two links to simulate the location you'd enter by url.

Comment: @user3007361, see comment above.